# Displaying different sets of data in the same UITableView based on conditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 3 lists to be displayed in a `UITableView` based on some conditions.

I am using a custom tableview cell to display it. So if the data is of the first set, I have to display total of 5 labels in a row; if it is of second set then I have to display 2 labels and for the 3rd set 1 label, and its alignment will be different.

By using a storyboard, can I display this kind of data?

Comment: No you can't do using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TableView sections to differentiate different data sets. You can switch off of the section to create the custom information for each dataset.

```
#pragma mark - UITableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection (NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger rows;
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            rows = firstSet.count;
            break;
        case 2:
            rows = secondSet.count;
            break;
        default:
            rows = 0;
            break;
    }
    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            //Custom cell for first section
            cell = [self customFirstSectionCell];
            break;
        case 2:
            //Custom cell for second section
            break;
        default:
            rows = 0;
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```